# How to use a selective regex to perform replace in a pandas series?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, pandas, series

I would like to use a regex when applying [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). I am aware that it takes in regex, but my output is not as intended. Here is a simple example. Suppose I have

```
ser = pd.Series(['asd3', 'qwe3', 'asd4', 'zxc'])
```

I would like to turn the `'asd3'` and `'asd4'` into `'asd'`. That is, simply removing any integer at the end. I am using the code:

```
ser.str.replace('asd([0-9])','')
```

Bote that I am using the `([0-9])` notation, which I interpret as saying: for any element of the series, if it looks like `'asd([0-9])'`, then replace the `[0-9]` with `` (that is, remove it). But what I get is

```
0    
1  qwe3
2    
3  zxc
```

whereas what I would like to get is:

```
0  asd
1  qwe3
2  asd
3  zxc
```

this is a simple example, and my regex string is uglier than that, but I hope this conveys the idea of what I intend to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, `.replace('asd([0-9])','')` just removes `asd` and any digit after it.

Use

```
ser.str.replace('asd[0-9]+','asd')
```

or

```
ser.str.replace('(asd)[0-9]+',r'\1')
```

The `.replace('asd[0-9]+','asd')` will replace `asd` and any 1+ digits after it with `asd`, and in `.replace('(asd)[0-9]+',r'\1')`, the `asd` substring will be captured into Group 1 (due to the capturing parentheses) and 1+ digits will be matched, and the whole match will be replaced with the `\1` placeholder that holds the value of Group 1 (that is, `asd`).